# How to consume the SSRS URL as WCF service in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, reporting-services

I am having Reporting Server hosted in DB Server. How can i access the Reporting service URL as WCF service in Web application.

I am able to access SSRS Report Server URL using c# with out any issue, but i want to access the SSRS Report Server URL from WCF Service or API.

Can any one help on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use SSRS SOAP API to access all the functions of SSRS, you can refer to [Integrating Reporting Services Using SOAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-soap?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and [Accessing the SOAP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/accessing-the-soap-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)